# TypeScript - Initialise property from another JavaScript file

Tags: typescript, firebase

I am using TypeScript and Firebase together.

My class has `fireybase: FirebaseInterface;` property.

When I initialise it using `this.fireybase = new Firebase('URL/');`

I get a compile time error about the `Firebase` object.

```
The name 'Firebase' does not exist in the current scope

interface FirebaseInterface {
    set(s:string): any;
}
```

I have tried adding a Firebase interface into the library but it still doesn't like it.

What is the best approach to doing this in TypeScript?

Comment: I dont know anything about Firebase, but correct me if i am wrong, I see `this.fireybase` in your code. IS there supposed to be a `y` in your "fireybase"?? Just checking to see if this is not a [PEBKAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error) error.

Comment: Max: a bit more code would be extremely helpful to spotting the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typescript compiler tells you that it is unable to find type `Firebase` so you need to introduce it. In your case, if the providers of the firebase library want to support development in Typescript, they would need to provide a declarations file that specifies the type `Firebase` (and dependendant types). In your case, a simple `Firebase.d.ts` file might look as follows:

**Firebase.d.ts**

```
declare class Firebase {    
    constructor(u:string);    
    set(s:string): any;
}
```

Then you need to bring the declarations file into scope with a reference declaration as follows:

**MyApp.ts**

```
///<reference path='firebase.d.ts'/>
class MyApp {  
    fireybase: Firebase;  
    constructor () => {
        this.fireybase = new Firebase('URL/');
    }
}
```

You can read more about declaration files and reference paths in the [language specification](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267238).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a reference to a module that contains the Firebase static definitions. Maybe a quick fix would be to use the following statement at the top of the file:

`declare var Firebase: any;`